# generate Flex thumbnail using command line

Tags: apache-flex

I have implemented a graph generator using flex. The user can edit his graph at any time. I want to save an image of this graph on the server without uploading it from the user PC. Is there a command line tool that can be used to start a flex program and pass some external parameters (file name) and store the file locally on the server ?

PS : I can convert my flex application to adobe air application if needed and use it from the server from command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I want to save an image of this graph on the server without uploading it from the user PC
```

I think you're out of luck.  There is no way to take something generated on a client and put it on the server w/o uploading it in some manner.  This is the same whether you use Flex or AIR (or Silverlight or HTML or JavaScript or any other client server technology of your choice).

Even with a command line program, it's going to have to esnd something to the server--or be running on the server--in order to save files there.

You're going to either have to upload the image to the server or send the data to the server and regenerate the graph based on the data.

Comment: Can I generate a AIR that can be called from command( on the server) line and generate the image ?

Comment: AIR isn't really designed for command line execution; but I guess--in theory--you could create an app w/ no UI that does processing based on command line arguments and then shuts itself down.